# Responding to imperfectly phrased questions

Tags: discussion, closing, deletion, proposal

When a question is phrased in a way considered not suitable for m.s.e., often within seconds it collects numerous down-votes and votes to close.  There's no way to know who down-voted, nor who voted to close except when the question ultimately gets closed, but long experience shows that many people who habitually participate in this practice have hair-triggers.  That's really really easy to do and maybe they feel they're maintaining the quality of the site.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867587/iiint-xyz-dxdydz-over-positive-octant-sphere-x2y2z2-4-please-help) quickly got three down-votes and a vote to close.  **Superficially,** it looks like a question about how to do a certain step necessary to evaluate a certain integral.  Another thing that's really easy to do without thinking at all is to take such superficial appearances literally.

What I would propose to do with questions of this kind is not to do the problem for them, but to tell them what they ought to be told about the subject matter.  I hope the answer I posted does that.  When one has observed that numerous students' confusion about this is not about a technical matter of how to proceed in executing a standard algorithm, but rather a lack of conceptual understanding, and one knows that the students themselves don't realize that that's what it is, then one may know that what the student needs to know is not the same as what the question says.

If proposed deletions had to be actually **discussed** (as with new Wikipedia articles whose deletion is proposed) then those with hair-triggers who vote first and think later might find out that they are capable of intelligent participation in reasoned argument. They would also find out that the world is bigger than what they can see.

I propose that a discussion page be created for each article that someone wants to close, and the decision on whether to close it would ensue from the discussion.

**PS:** It seems to me that the convention that says the poster should show some effort should really be construed as meaning they should show that they understand the question.  Our systems of schooling provide some obvious incentives for some students to post questions that they don't understand.  (And that is an indictment of those systems, including the concept of a "curriculum".)  However, we have a nuance: Supposing it falls short of being proved that the poster understands the question.  One kind of answer that frequently appears is a complete and detailed answer to the question and all "i"s dotted and "t"s crossed.  Another is subtler: One can surmise that if a student is having difficulty answering the particular question, then understanding of one particular idea may be lacking, and one's explanation of that idea might be phrased in such a way that those who understand the question are likely to understand the answer, but no solution for those who don't understand the question is found in it.  In the particular question I linked to above, it is probable that the poster does understand the question; hence the votes to close were not a good idea in the first place.  However, if not, then the kind of answer I posted might match the description above, of the second kind of answer.  Those with hair-triggers might benefit from calibration that they won't get if their votes to close are just drive-by votes and they'll never be back.

Comment: FWIW I upvoted this (meta)question. Not because I agree with the proposal, but it is IMHO important to occasionally re-evaluate our policies.

Comment: The first problem I have is that what superficial aspects about the question (in main) are not what they seem? The integration looks very straightforward to me. That question is unlikely to add answers of lasting value to the material collected on our site. Can you elaborate a bit on what is exceptional about this question?

Comment: I do agree with your observation that we have some very trigger-happy close voters. Judging from their profiles some users vote to close questions they are themselves totally clueless about.

Comment: The main problem I have with your example question is the plea for *a complete answer*. To many veterans this is a polite way of asking somebody to do my homework assignment for me. I acknowledge that it is not clear how a totally confused student should best ask a question in such a way that **the only answers would help the asker learn**. With your example question an obvious possibility is to help with the limits of integration only. Glad to see you took up the task of trying to address exactly that.

Comment: IMO there are too many closures for a prolonged discussion in a dedicated thread to be a feasible workflow. I do see that your proposal is about deletions rather than closures. There are less deletions, but I still have some reservations about having a separate thread for each case. After all, most of them are not contentious. As a diamond moderator I act in the obvious cases without any ado. We would need some stats to guess whether meta would be overwhelmed by such threads.

Comment: Anyway, we have adopted the approach that we react and vote first, and if there is notable disagreement, we use the dedicated meta thread to collect more opinions. Not ideal, perhaps, but very efficient. May be you think it is too efficient? Or, do you think we should do a better job in advertising all this? I welcome suggestions about how to inform our user base about this! Meta is the default venue, and it is not unreasonable to think that the interested users can find their way here.

Comment: Actually I did have in mind closures.  I suspect the discussions in very many cases would not be particularly prolonged, but that would remain to be seen. However, even someone who is not clueless about the topic of the question would often learn from a discussion that there is more to the matter than they suspect, and will fail to learn that from a drive-by instantaneous "close" vote. $\qquad$

Comment: "Can you elaborate a bit on what is exceptional about this question?" I don't think of anything as being exceptional about it.  But there may be a superficial appearance that it says in effect "Do this problem for me". Even if that's what the poster intended, the question is an opportunity to post a good answer that might help both the person who asked the question and other people, by telling them what they ought to know about the matter they asked about, even if it doesn't directly answer what was asked.  I've notice other questions about which that can be said. $\qquad$

Comment: (-1) for the entirety of paragraph 4. Perhaps people could also discover that reasonable people can have differences of opinion on this matter, and that some of us actually **do** think before we cast closure / deletion votes. Of course, if one approaches from that perspective, they wouldn't think that people aren't capable of having "intelligent participation in reasoned argument."

Comment: Also, I would (-1) for the proposal itself. There are dozens of closures daily, and the volume of questions means that it is simply not feasible to discuss them individually. Such a proposal would be the antithesis of the SE model of giving users progressively more trust / privileges as they gain experience on the site.

Comment: @T.Bongers : Indeed, reasonable people can have differences of opinion. Does the fact that reasonable people can have differences of opinion mean they shouldn't talk about them?  Drive-by down-votes with no words prevent the drive-by down-voters from ever finding out about that, and prevent others from ever finding out what the drive-by down-voters opinion is.  Drive-by down-voters are neither reasonable people nor people who have any opinions. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy "Drive-by down-voters" do have opinions, and are expressing them - otherwise they wouldn't go to the effort or cost of voting. Perhaps they refrain from commenting because of the frequent abuse by some of the [more aggressively moralistic users](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/can-we-be-nicer-to-downvoters). But that's not the point of your question, is it: you *were* asking above closures and deletion votes, which are guaranteed to have a name attached if the action is completed.

Comment: And my previous comment was not to imply that we shouldn't discuss these issues. It was to point out the fact that **yet again** you are making a condescending meta post where you question the intelligence and forthrightness and reasonability of your fellow users.

Comment: *Saying the following in a gentle slow slightly deep and pleasant voice*: After seeing your meta-post here I took about 5 sec. to decide to vote to close the question for lack of context. I don't think this question has anything to do with what the question is about. The problem is the question is solely that it lacks any attempt and context.

That said, I do think you do a good job at trying to help the OP in your answer.

Comment: Ok. Cool it, please, both of you. That fourth paragraph can be seen as condescending, but try to ignore that. Let's rather use this opportunity to educate each other about the origin of the differences of opinion. Michael, have you read the earlier discussions on this theme? If you do, you will undoubtedly see that you are not alone voicing the opinion that we should not close threads like that.

Comment: Michael, in a sense the users voting to close those questions are thinking that they are doing their "civic duty". A heated discussion in meta lead to a conclusion that we have this "no context" close reason. The discussions revealed a strong sentiment that the site should not be used as a place to get homework done without having to think. You don't have to share that sentiment, but many users genuinely feel that way. So they think that the act of voting to close some questions is not unlike picking up garbage some litterer dropped on their home street.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that going after those individual voters will not really help your cause, when the general policy is what you apparently want to get re-evaluated and possibly also altered. The current policy is not nearly universally accepted, but also some would prefer an even tougher stand and ban homework questions altogether. This policy is already a kind of a compromise even though it may not look like one.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : "they think that the act of voting to close some questions is not unlike picking up garbage some litterer dropped on their home street." Probably they think that.  When they are right in thinking there's something wrong with a question, others who don't know what's wrong with the question will not find out, and when they are wrong, they will never find out that they are wrong, nor why they are wrong. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael: Those opinions (as well as the opposing opinions) were written in those meta discussions. Accompanying each and every close in main with a quick recap is hardly efficient.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I meant opinions on particular questions in main, when closing them is proposed. $\qquad$

Comment: Discussions are needed to make users aware of where the others stand, but they must stay in meta. I have more or less given up hope of finding a palatable compromise. People are unlikely to cross the aisle as a consequence of this kind of exchanges. But if they understand why others feel the way they do, they can act accordingly and not be surprised, when others react differently to a given situation.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I did [propose a policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10962/11619) with the idea that close voters should "know what they are doing" (and the first close voter could leave a comment). That proposal never won enough support. Also, the volume of traffic (and consequently also the volume of questionable posts) has increased a lot since that day.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Do you have any evidence for the claim that "those with hair triggers and those who are non-verbal probably generally know less than others"?

Comment: @T.Bongers : Yes.  Much but not all of the evidence I could cite for that comes from contexts other than m.s.e.  But the reason why it might work that way should be clear if you think about it for a moment.  Start with the commonplace observation that among students in freshman-level courses, the ones who think they know everything are the ones who know the least$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$and then notice that a few simple rules (such as the idea that a poster should at least show some understanding of the posted question) are easy to grasp but the reasons for recognizing some nuances rather than being overly rigid in the application of such rules take a lot more effort to understand. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy On the other hand, the vast majority of closures happen in tags like [tag:algebra-precalculus] or [tag:calculus] (read: low-level tags that are likely to have homework assigned), where the **vast** majority of close-voters are going to be very well experienced with the subject matter.

Comment: And as a separate point: I'd find your complaints about "drive-by downvoters" a lot more compelling if down/close-voters had to be involved in reopening a question. They don't need to be, since any five users with enough rep can reopen. There is absolutely no need to convince anyone to change their minds on any given vote.

Comment: @T.Bongers : Experience in the subject matter confers no understanding of the kinds of students who often show up.  For example, not long ago someone posted a question that said "Dividing 2240000/1111 seems to give 2016.20162016... to infinity. That is, 2016 keeps repeating. Can someone please tell me what the probability of this is?" Some otherwise intelligent people construed this literally as a question about calculating a probability! People who understand the math very thoroughly can be as clueless as that about students in elementary courses! $\qquad$

Comment: @T.Bongers : But drive-by downvoters are often _serial_ drive-by downvoters, who could learn to do it better if given the opportunity. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy To extend Jyrki's analogy: People who pick up litter on the street are often *serial* waste collectors, who could learn to just leave it there if given the opportunity. In my opinion (which is apparently shared by many others and disagreed with by many others), there are questions which are simply bad and deserve to be closed without further  controversy or effort. To phrase this as "if only I could teach those I disagree with they could learn to be good" is not a productive way to approach this.

Comment: @T.Bongers : There are limits on anaolgies.  We see problems with the way that works in this case. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy there is a third option for 2016etc (and this applies to numerous discussion of this form). Namely not to think it should be asked like an exact probability question, but to recognize there are different interpretations to the question and OP should state, possibly with guidance, which they want. Somebody could also go around saying those that do not want it closed are  not smart or experienced  enough to recognize that there is a multitude of potential questions lurking there.

Comment: @quid I tend to agree with your last comment. A question that has ten valid interpretations is just as bad as a question that has zero valid interpretations, and *both* need to be clarified by the asker.

Comment: @T.Bongers : To expect students' questions always to be clear would be unreasonable (and, I'm tempted to say in many cases would be stupid). One should ask them to try to be clear, but one should realize that will often not succeed. Moreover, one should become familiar with the usual ways in which they misunderstand things, since that will enable one to understand things they say that would be incomprehensible if the terms were construed in the way in which mathematicians carefully define them.

Comment: Michael, I don't expect that student questions are always going to be clear - most of the time, if the student was capable of phrasing the question perfectly clearly, they would be able to answer it. Yet I also don't bend over backwards to give askers a convoluted and contrived interpretation of their question that may have absolutely nothing to do with what they're asking. If a question is best answered by a psychic, it's off-topic here.

Comment: @T.Bongers : I don't bend over backwards either, and I certainly would avoid things that are convoluted and contrived.  Nor does one become a psychic by doing what I suggested: "one should become familiar with the usual ways in which they misunderstand things, since that will enable one to understand things they say that would be incomprehensible if the terms were construed in the way in which mathematicians carefully define them." $\qquad$

Comment: If it's not clear to the reader and also not clear to the poster what the poster is asking, and the poster himself says so, it may in some cases be perfectly clear that it's a very good question and perfectly clear how it should be answered.  It seems that some people don't know that. (T. Bongers reports that he does not know that.)  m.s.e. would be better if it facilitated learning that, rather than hindering it.  It is clear that mere familiarity with the mathematics does not confer any understanding of that point.  I'm going to try to start collecting examples. $\qquad$

Answer (score 9):

Superficially I left a Comment before voting to close, so maybe I'm "off the hook" here.

But I think the idea of closing a Question when the OP doesn't respond to collective comments/requests for clarification by editing is to have a bit of a cooling off period.  Ideally the OP (or someone who feels confident in editing the Question on their behalf) will make the changes needed to get Community buy-in that some learning will be taking place.  In my case I think the effort or other explanation of context to get my Reopen vote is pretty modest.

Deleting such Questions before the "on-hold" phase has a chance to run its course is another matter.  I disagree with that, at least in this case.  The Question has a decent "teaching moment" opportunity in it (how to set up limits of integration), and deleting it would be overly punitive IMHO.

In any case putting a Question on-hold and getting it reopened is a fairly painless process, and I hope it works out here for the OP and someone with a desire to assist in their learning.

**Added 7/24/16** The Delete campaign ran its course (successfully), in tandem with the Reopen campaign, and then it became possible to cast Undelete votes.  I cast the final one, and the Question is now undeleted with the on-hold status the subject of a fair number of reopen votes intact.

One reason I don't like to see Questions deleted while the on-hold status is in effect is that it inhibits editing to fix any perceived textual problems.

A minor example:  In this case the OP had written that "Complete answer will be appreciated," which incurred a comment, "but that is **not** the mission of this website."  If instead the OP had phrased this as "hints posted as Answers are not wanted," I would be entirely sympathetic with that sentiment.

Answer (score 2):

Seems sensible to add this observation: there are users who, exclusively in some cases, ask contest preparation questions. That is, there may or may not be a teacher supervising any aspect of the student's activities with regard to these questions. An example is https://math.stackexchange.com/users/297795/puzzled417 The source of some of the questions is a book/website with all questions that were merely proposed for past Olympiads, most of them never used. One question posted here was an open problem, good thing it was not used in an actual contest  [Prove that $\gcd(3^n-2,2^n-3)=\gcd(5,2^n-3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824629/prove-that-gcd3n-2-2n-3-gcd5-2n-3)

Let's see, I left a comment to this effect, a few minutes ago, at [Find the integer solutions of $\sin\frac \pi {2n} + \cos\frac \pi {2n} = \frac{\sqrt n} 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868742/find-the-integer-solutions-for-n-in-sin-dfrac-pi-2n-cos-dfrac-pi-2n/1868744#comment3828293_1868744)  For this particular question, my opinion may or may not be borne out.

Comment: Although this is probably true (and definitely possible in the recent case you linked): The asker is the one ultimately responsible for a bad question, regardless of whether they received the question in the bad form. If they don't understand the question, they can ask for clarification on what they do have; if they just copy-paste it, it's no better. I don't think your answer is advocating for this, but I really fail to understand the view of those who would say "We should leave it open because it was incomprehensible when the OP got it too."

Comment: @T.Bongers right. I want the questions to be just a little beyond what the OP can currently do, so some kind of response actually does help their progress, and it does not require re-writing a book chapter to get them to understand.

Comment: @T.Bongers meanwhile, I am more of a closer than an opener. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Night_in_the_Lonesome_October